# What is the default timeout when calling the Facebook API using C# SDK?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Below is the code used to connect to the Facebook API, will it have a default timeout? I was wondering this because I think this code should be put in a `try/catch` statement in case the request to Facebook times out.

```
ConnectSession _connectSession = new ConnectSession(GetApplicationKey(), GetSecretKey());
Api _facebookAPI = new Api(_connectSession);
_facebookAPI.Friends.Get();
```

Does anyone know the default time out (if any) for the above calls? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally its somewhere around 12s.  You can see time out reports in your application insights to help debug and monitor them.